# How to make UIView above UINavigationController in Storyboard?

Tags: c#, ios, swift, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have created a UIView in storyboard for overlay propose. I want the view above my navigation controller, I know its possible to do it programmatically but is it possible to do it on storyboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have to have some kind of parent view controller that contains your navigation controller, then you could create another subview that is a sibling of the navigation controller's view and could overlay it above.

[image]